# "Behaves similar to" or "behaves similarly to"?

Tags: comparisons

I wrote the following comment in a programming forum:

> Objects in JavaScript behave similar to a regular associative array.

This is how I would use the word "similar" in normal conversation. However, the dictionary says that "similar" is an adjective, and "similarly" should be used in this context instead:

> Objects in JavaScript behave *similarly* to a regular associative array.

Both constructions look grammatically correct to me, but the second one sounds weird. Searching the internet, I see both "behaves similar to" and "behaves similarly to" are used.

So are both considered grammatically correct?

Comment: Personally, I would phrase it "behave *like*". BTW, you want to say "associatIVE array" (not "associate array").

Comment: @DanBron - Oh good catch.

Comment: i would not use *like* in this case. "behave like" can mean "behave exactly like" (at least to a programmer), and that is not the intent here.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/83110 But there is a problem with this whole idea. The behavior of X might be similar to Y’s behavior, but X’s behavior is not similar to Y.  It is similar to Y’s.

Comment: I think if we start pulling threads here, the cloth unravels. Objects don't really behave, they're acted upon. And one could argue they are a type of associate array, not similar to one (religious wars start in 3... 2...).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In casual speech you can probably get away with *similar*, but you may sound uneducated to some. *Similarly* is the correct adverb form, and it does not sound weird. I would always write *similarly* in this case. The same is true for *different* and *differently*.

---

As a side note, this sentence lacks subject-verb agreement:

*Objects in JavaScript behaves similarly to a regular associate array.*

It should be:

*Objects in JavaScript **behave** similarly to regular associate **arrays**.*

(Also, the correct term is *associative* array)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it (and correcting my sentence too.)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 But you are in good company. Apple's motto is *Think Different*.

Comment: This doesn’t work. They behave similarly to how something else behaves. They do not behave similarly to something else, because that does not make sense.

Comment: @tchrist if you understood the intended meaning (i think you did), it makes sense. i agree your example would be considered "more correct" in a writing class or other formal setting, but what i wrote still makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The correct word in this usage is *similarly*.

In a hypothetical situation where there is a test for similarity, and two object are, when tested, found to be similar, then one could say either object *behaves similar to* the other.  There is no such "similar to" test defined in JavaScript.