# "X behaves identical to Y" or "X behaves identically to Y"

Tags: grammar

I thought

> *an object X behaves **identically** to an object Y*

would be correct, because the adverb *identically* modifies the verb *behaves*.

But

> *an object X behaves **identical** to an object Y*

does not sound wrong in my ears. Would you say that it is completely wrong to have the adjective *identical* modify the verb *behaves*?

Comment: To me, it sounds awkwardly phrased either way. "Object X's and Object Y's behavior is identical" sounds more natural.

Comment: @Nicole Americans often tend to avoid adverbs, and that could explain why the sentence you quote sounds 'more natural'. In Britain the use of adverbs is encouraged as a part of good English (or at least it was - I cannot speak for the modern generation of teachers). I would find it perfectly natural to say *Object X behaves identically to object Y*.

Comment: I don't have a problem with either, but note this from Google Books... [*behaves identical to*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22behaves+identical+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl): about 188 results, [*behaves identically to*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22behaves+identically+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): about 6720 results.

Comment: I'd say X and Y exhibit identical behavior.

Comment: @WS2 I'm not sure where you got that idea; Americans use adverbs all the time. (Some misuse an adjective when they mean to use an adverb, but that's another issue.) The original sentence is awkward because it's unnecessarily wordy, not because it uses an adverb.

Comment: @Nicole wordy an in uses to many words? How so, when 'object X behaves identically to object Y' has 7 words (if you omit the two indefinite articles) while 'Object X's and object Y's behavior is identical' has 8 words in it? I'm not a native speaker, but the difference between the two sounds more like a 'to-may-to/to-mah-to' situation to me :-)

Comment: You have to compare like with like, so the first object behaves indentically to how the second object behaves. See [“A similar hat to Jane” vs “A hat similar to Jane’s”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/83110/2085)

Comment: I've been trying to work out a similar problem: The four dancing couples dressed identically to the dancers in the painting. or The four dancing couples dressed identical to the dancers in the painting. Adverbs can usually be moved about, but then the second sentence would read The four dancing couples identically dressed to the dancers in the painting. Something else is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I would say that

> it is completely wrong to have the adjective "identical" modify the verb "behaves"

since an adjective modifies nouns, not verbs; a similar example might be

> this was phrased bad.

However, if you rephrased the sentence to refer to the noun "behaviour",

> X's behaviour was identical to Y's

should be OK.