# Which is correct: “as” vs “to”?

Tags: grammaticality, comparisons

On a sister site, [there is a difference of opinion where each claims the other is a grammatical error](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/64777/revisions) (look at revisions 4 and 5).

Option Ω:

> …, with a similar effect on humans **to** Wolbachia in pillbugs, …

Option ζ:

> …, with a similar effect on humans **as** Wolbachia **shows** in pillbugs, …

Is either of these wrong?  If both correct, do they mean different things?

The Worldbuilding SE is filled with better than average writing and caters to a more literary audience. So it’s a serious question, and following up on these things will reflect in later published works.

Comment: Neither is "wrong," but both are a bit awkward. You might want to try something more straightforward: "What if a bacterium **had the same** effect **on** humans **that** Wolbachia **has on** pillbugs, …"? etc. Would this work for you?

Comment: Certainly it was awkward, with the most significant fact tucked away in a “non essential” parenthetical phrase.  That’s a literal example of **burying** the lede!  My question is whether either can be considered a grammatical error.  (It’s possible that Ω and ζ were referring to some other words)

Comment: It *may* be a BrE vs AmE thing, but as a native speaker of AmE, I'm firmly in the "as - shows" camp. However, both versions are grammatical, and they are both understandable. Drop the "on humans" and you'll see that both still work.

Comment: The construction is << similar to / >> / << a similar [effect] to that of X in >>. I'd say ζ is ungrammatical, and Ω unfelicitous (paralleling 'effect', an eventuality and 'Wolbachia', a bacterium).

Comment: Wording along the lines of "whose effect on humans was similar to Wolbachia's on pillbugs" seems closer to normal informal U.S. English phrasing than any of the options that might emerge from the beginning "with a similar effect on humans..."

Answer (score 1):

Given these two choices:

1. What if a bacterium, with a **similar** effect on humans **to** Wolbachia in pillbugs, rapidly spread through our world in the early 21st century?
2. What if a bacterium, with a **similar** effect on humans **as** Wolbachia **shows** in pillbugs, rapidly spread through our world in the early 21st century?

Neither is always considered wrong by all speakers. However, version (1) where *similar* and *to* are so far separated ***can*** sound quite strange to some speakers, especially in those not used to hearing constructions like that. To them it may not necessarily sound grammatical, or sensible, or clear.

As [this related question shows](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/83110/2085), whenever you split *similar to* up by putting other words between those two, you risk confusing folks. My own preference is therefore to rephrase so as to keep *similar to* intact with no other words falling between them. That leads to such choices as these, ranging from more verbose to less so:

3. What if a bacterium that affected humans **similar*ly* to** how the *Wolbachia* bacterium affects pillbugs were to spread rapidly throughout our world in the early 21st century?
4. What if a bacterium with an effect in humans that’s **similar to** the effect that the *Wolbachia* bacterium has in pillbugs were to spread rapidly throughout our world in the early 21st century?
5. What if a bacterium with an effect in humans that’s **similar to** that of *Wolbachia* in pillbugs spread rapidly throughout our world in the early 21st century?
6. What if a bacterium with an effect in humans that’s **similar to** *Wolbachia***’s** in pillbugs spread rapidly throughout our world in the early 21st century?
7. What if a bacterium with an effect in humans **similar to** *Wolbachia***’s** in pillbugs spread rapidly throughout our world in the early 21st century?

Any of those is likely to come across as clearer but nonetheless wordier than the original. Personal patience for wordiness will always vary depending on the writer. For example, notice how the last two use a possessive form with *-’s* to allow skipping the second instance of *effect*, but that elision may not be as clear to all speakers as spelling it out more explicitly.  The more you chop out, the more you risk people getting a misreading, as least on their first or second time through.

Comment: Why “that’s”? Generally in academic writing such speech abbreviations are written in full.  Otherwise I would favour 4. But the “early 21st century” sounds ridiculousl. Drop it.

Comment: @David I don't think I should change [somebody else’s quote](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/64777/what-would-happen-if-a-bacterium-hijacked-human-gender-determination).

Comment: It's not academic writing, it's a forum for fantasy writers.